# Select field with apostrophe SQL

Tags: sql, field, apostrophe

I have a FIELD *doctor's patient* with an apostrophe from the table *emergency*

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM emergency."doctor''s patient"
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Columns (not "fields") can't be referenced in the `from` clause. And inside an quoted identifier there is no need to escape the single quotes, so it should be `select "doctor's patient" from emergency` (but that depends partially on how standard compliant the DBMS is that you are using)

Answer (score 1):

you can try following way.

```
SELECT [doctor'spatient] FROM emergency
```

Comment: That non-standard SQL. You should mention to which DBMS this answer applies

Answer (score 1):

Very poor design, but I've seen it done.  Also seen it with spaces in the name. You have both. If using SQL Server, as @mahabub suggested, enclose the names in [square brackets], as in:

```
select [doctor's patient] from [emergency]
```

That being said, you can also use the [SET QUOTED IDENTIFIER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-quoted-identifier-transact-sql) command to allow you to use double quotes to delimit names, e.g.,

```
select "doctor's patient" from "emergency"
```

Comment: Good point.  I added an unnecessary value judgement. Removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised the database let that column name go by. Special characters in names are generally taboo.  If you are not the DBA, I would recommend talking with them to rename the field without the apostrophe, and without the space. It will make life easier.

On to the query, try escaping the apostrophe as in \'

`SELECT * FROM emergency.'doctor\'s patient';` or

```
SELECT * FROM emergency."doctor\'s patient";
```